# Present View Controller modally from xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a xib file associated to a UIViewController custom class (ZocaloPlayerViewController)

[image]

and im trying to present a UIViewController (made in storyboard) modally with flip horizontal

[image]

but i am getting an error:

This is how im trying to present the view controller

```
ShowDetailsArtistAlbumViewController *vc = [[ShowDetailsArtistAlbumViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShowDetailsArtistAlbumViewController" bundle:nil];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

But i am getting this error...

```
Uncaught exception: Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/57C2AD20-51DB-4C43-BB8F-2E8F22CD2E2A/MyMusicApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'ShowDetailsArtistAlbumViewController'
```

I was trying with

```
[self.parentViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

But nothing happens...

EDIT:
I tried this way

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ShowDetailsArtistAlbumViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShowDetailsArtistAlbumViewController"];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

The view controller is presented but im getting a black view but nothing inside

Answer (score 3):

You say "I have a xib file associated" but the problem is that you don't. The runtime is looking for a xib file called *ShowDetailsArtistAlbumViewController.xib* but you don't have one. You need to rename your *xib* file to match the expectations of the runtime.

Alternatively, you may be creating your view controller incorrectly. You are saying this:

```
ShowDetailsArtistAlbumViewController *vc = 
    [[ShowDetailsArtistAlbumViewController alloc] 
        initWithNibName:@"ShowDetailsArtistAlbumViewController" bundle:nil];
```

That is why the runtime thinks you have a nib called *ShowDetailsArtistAlbumViewController.xib* - you are telling it that, right there in that line!

That's fine if there is in fact a nib called *ShowDetailsArtistAlbumViewController.xib*. Your problem is there is not. You have lied to the runtime and so naturally it crashes.

If you actually wanted to use the view controller *in the storyboard*, that's *not* how to access that instance. What you are doing is creating a *different* instance. If you want the instance in the storyboard, you need to *talk to the storyboard* and tell it to `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`.

Comment: Im was explaining myself wrong. The view controller i want to present is made in storyboard. Look the EDIT in my question.

Comment: You're not listening to what I said. It doesn't matter how the view controller is instantiated. The error message means the runtime is looking for a xib file called _ShowDetailsArtistAlbumViewController.xib_ but you don't have one.

Comment: matt, i understood, but if the view controller is made in storyboard, where i have to put the nib name? please look i edited the question with images...

Comment: If the view controller is made in the storyboard, you usually don't use a separate _xib_ file. You use the design that's right there in the storyboard. You _can_ use a separate _xib_ file but that's not the normal thing.

Comment: You are saying `ShowDetailsArtistAlbumViewController *vc = [[ShowDetailsArtistAlbumViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShowDetailsArtistAlbumViewController" bundle:nil];` so you are _not_ using the one in the storyboard. Do you see?

Comment: ok, so how i can present a modal view controller made in storyboard from a function in a xib file (not made in storyboard)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105053/discussion-between-quetool-and-matt).